# Push element to existing array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a problem that I don't know how to resolve:

I have this code that pretty much asks user for date. The problem that I have is that I can't make the array to take var limit as an element whenever user puts a new date. The array resets itself whenever the method 'new_date' ends.

Here is the code:

```
def new_date 
  puts "Date please: "
  date1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
  d, m, y = date1.split('-').map{|x| x.to_i}
  limit = day_of_week(d, m, y)
  puts days_of_the_week[limit]
  $various_dates = []
  $various_dates.push(limit)
end
```

Comment: Yes it is ruby but can you please fix your indentation?

Comment: Why reinitialize `$various_dates` at the 7th last line?

Comment: Ok, I edit it. I tried '$various_dates' in several lines just for testing and none of them worked. They are gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not reset your array of dates in:

```
$various_dates = []
```

Instead, do something like:

```
$various_dates ||= []
```

What this does, is it gets the global variable `$various_dates`, but if it hasn't been initialized (which means that it is nil), it will be set to an empty array.

Comment: This is it! Thanks so much! :)